# Makehuman 1.0.2 Blender tools issues in Blender 2.72b

Tags: add-on, makehuman

Makehuman Blender tools from Makehuman v1.0.2 aren't showing after "install from file" in user preferences in stable version of Blender 2.72b.
Python console highlights green that the mhBlender tools have been placed in the correct folders for Blender to find them, but they don't show up in user prefs.

Another user had the same problems on the [Makehuman.org forum](http://forum.makehuman.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=11157&start=10), and a workaround was offered that worked for this guy, but it doesn't for me.

No problems with Makehuman working, only getting the Blender tools into Blender's user preferences. Same issue with Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!
The Makehuman sub-folders 'makeclothes', 'makewalk', 'maketarget' must be removed from the folder named Blender Tools ***before*** placing them inside Users/user name/Library/Application support/Blender/2.72/scripts/addons.
Any folder inside Blender's Addon folder must have a file named **init**.py; if it doesn't, Python will ignore the folder.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) for details of how Python uses **init**.py

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this: "**The Makehuman sub-folders 'makeclothes', 'makewalk', 'maketarget' must be removed from the folder named Blender Tools before placing them inside Users/user name/Library/Application support/Blender/2.72/scripts/addons.**"! NOTE: In Linux, change to **sudo su** before doing the copying of the sub-folders to /usr/... Worked great for me, thanks!!!